# The environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" in Google machines

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk, google-iam

### Background

I have a virtual machine running a code using Google SDK for diffrent products (like Google PubSub). According to Google documentation, my machine should have an environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and its values should be pointing to a clear text file that holding the service account of the application.

I have done it and it's working for me.

### The Problem

It sounds like an unsafe practice to store such a key, in plain text, inside a virtual machine. If the machine has been hacked, this key will be one of the first targets of the attacker.

I was expected to find a solution to "hide" this key file or just encrypt it with a key that my application will be able to read.

I found some code examples (C#), that allow the programmer to pass the credentials manually to the SDK functions. But, it's not a standard way to do it and it's being changed from one product to another (seems impossible in some products).

What is the best practice to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a good read at the following:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

This describes a concept called "Application Default Credentials".  The concept here is that a Compute Engine (a virtual machine) has a default service account (that you can configure) associated with it.  Applications running on the Compute Engine can thus make requests from that Compute Engine to other GCP services and the requests to those services will implicitly appear to come from the service account configured against the Compute Engine.

The key phrase in the article is:

> If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS **isn't** set, ADC uses the default service account that Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, Cloud Run, and Cloud Functions provide.

Comment: The `default service account` is uniform for all the services? is this possible to create service account permissions per application (because each application demand different permissions)?

Comment: The default service account is the default per Compute Engine instance.  What that means is that if you run multiple applications on the same machine, they will all have the same default service account.  However, if they run on separate machines, then they can each have distinct service accounts.  If you need per-app service accounts then see .. https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager